# Why can I not set context.fillStyle immediately after I create my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cross-browser

I am trying to follow along with the drawing canvas tutorial at [perfection kills](http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/)
and I have the following code:

```
let c = document.createElement('canvas')
document.body.appendChild(c)
let ctx = c.getContext("2d")

...(set canvas size)

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
console.log(ctx)
```

And the console shows that the fillStyle is still set to #000000 in firefox and electron shell. google chrome works completely as I would expect.

If I set the fillStyle later in the mousemove event handler that is used for drawing or set the value in the inspector console it works as expected.

If it makes a difference, the above code is the top in the top of my ready function bound to the DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: When you output an object to the console it can change. To ensure that the fillStyle is indeed "#000000" at the time you call console.log use console.log(ctx.fillStyle); as that will display the string which is a primitive type and will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue seems to be that the context is cleared/reset on canvas resize.